# What is the different tactics between sending the ball to near post and back post in football corner kick?

Tags: football, tactics

In football, some teams always send the ball to near post when they got a corner kick and they fail to score. I wonder why don't they try back post, or short corner kick.

Comment: you should narrow your question a lot more to come with a good answer. Any team could do anything they want with a corner kick, and the reasons to do that could be a lot. it can happen that they don't have a kicker that can kick that far away (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Corner kick

This is most of the time the option chosen if they have no real player who can head the ball in.

### Corner kick to back post

This one is the most trickiest of the options I would say. Giving a good ball to the furtest goal post can be difficult. It all has to be (fairly)good: speed, height, direction are very important. 5cm too high and it's a bad kick, too low, too close to the goalkeeper, too slow, bad kick. Good height and speed but wrong direction, bad kick. No matter how good a player's shooting, it's still tricky and offcourse highly dependable on how players run and are allowed to run by their defender.

### Corner kick to nearest post

This gives you a bit more options, you can pass the ball back, head it trough, take a shot/header at goal. Here a good kick is also important but if things go wrong there are some things to fall back on which are less possible with a kick to the furthest post. You also don't need the biggest players to manage a header there. A defender will most likely remain behind the player which gives him a better chance than heading for a kick going further in. A bad